# Looking to open a .CAD file on a mac?

Tags: 3d, cad, macos

I need to view a file that originated in a program called CADStd. This produces a .CAD filetype. Unfortunately, I'm on a MAC and this program is only available on Windows. Is there any other software that will be able to open this file type?

Comment: CADStd is not a major CAD application. You can't rely on the ".cad" file extension since other CAD programs may also use the same extension. CADStd can export as DXF. If possible perhaps you can get the person who created the files to export to DXF. Many programs can import DXF.

Answer (score -1):

There are free programs available at [Source Forge](https://sourceforge.net). This is a repository for free open source software? There is a free CAD program [BRL-CAD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/brlcad/). This code is widely used and actively maintained. It should be able to open your .CAD file. It runs on a Mac.

There is also another CAD program available called [Free Cad](https://sourceforge.net/projects/free-cad/).  This program has been recently updated and has almost 3000 downloads this week. You can read about them at the links provided.

Comment: CADStd is not a major CAD program. Have you actually checked to make sure that the programs you cite open CADStd files? You can't just rely on the extension as different programs could use the same ".cad" extension.

Comment: I don't think BRL-CAD will work based on its documentation: http://brlcad.org/w/images/6/66/Converting_Geometry.pdf. FreeCad also doesn't list CADstd's file format: https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Feature_list